# Can I answer this question with "do"?

Tags: grammar

Can I answer this question with "do"?

> For example,
>
> A: Are you living in the county now?
>
> B: Yes, I do.

Can we?

According to my grammar book, I think B should answer "Yes, I'm".
But I just got an answer from a native speaker that it's okay.

Is it correct to answer "do" instead of "am" informally despite grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering **"Yes, I do."** to the question **"Are you living in the county now?"** is grammatically incorrect and, while still conveying the correct meaning, would sound awkward, even in an informal conversation.

A more grammatically appropriate answer would be **"Yes, I am."**

You can more easily see that this is correct by completing the thought that is being conveyed:

**"Yes, I do living in the county now."** (Incorrect)

**"Yes, I am living in the county now."** (Correct)

Another thing to note is that the contraction of "I'm" sounds awkward when used by itself.

For example:

**"Yes, I'm."** should be **"Yes, I am,"** whereas if you explicitly state what/where you are, the contraction works: **"Yes, I'm living in the county now."**

Comment: A detailed explanation for why you can't end a sentence with "I'm" can be found on ELU [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2547/191178).

Comment: @Laurel There is no syntactic reason that you can't use the contraction. So, that explanation isn't really objectively coherent. The simple reason that it's *wrong* is just that we *don't*. It's an idiomatic thing where the answer is *because*. (It sounds wrong because nobody ever says it that way.)